# Handling association entries in custom POST PUT and PATCH requests in spring data rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have a requirement wherein I have to have custom business logic in the POST, PATCH and PUT endpoints. Using SDR events is not a possibility since I would need to do a couple of transactional operation in the request. So, I decided to create my custom endpoint for the entity which is attached to the repository by a service class.

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/myEntity")
@ExposesResourceFor(MyEntity.class)
public class MyEntityResource {
    @PostMapping(value = "", produces = MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity postResult(@RequestBody Entity entity) {
        // my logic
    }
}
```

Now I am facing an issue where my POST request can have association links to other entities. The default implementation of SDR handles this gracefully but I am facing a Jackson mapping error.

`` JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.foo.bar.Entity` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('/api/v1/entity/12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012') ``

Thus I looked up how Spring's implementation is and I have found the following method

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = BASE_MAPPING, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<ResourceSupport> postCollectionResource(RootResourceInformation resourceInformation,
        PersistentEntityResource payload, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler,
        @RequestHeader(value = ACCEPT_HEADER, required = false) String acceptHeader)
```

and I have found that the `PersistentEntityResource payload` gets populated with the fetched associated entity and the main entity gets saved by a normal save call to the repository.

So, I tried autowiring `PersistentEntityResource` but that fails essentially because the invoker of `PersistentEntityResource` expects the mapping url to be of the form `/{repository}/<optional id>` and as I already know what my path is, `PersistentEntityResource` is unable to initialise. It also doesn't help that `PersistentEntityResource` is not generic (it was upto SDR 2.0.0.M1 after which it was removed). Also being able to use `PersistentEntityResource` would have made implementing PATCH and PUT a lot easier too.

Is there any way to to handle this?

Comment: Event handlers are transactional.

Comment: @AlanHay Are they under the same transaction as the SDR call itself?

Comment: The whole SDR request is embedded into a transaction via a filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after some digging. On hindsight, it's pretty trivial. Just use `Resource<Entity>` instead of `Entity` in the method paramaters.

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/myEntity")
@ExposesResourceFor(MyEntity.class)
public class MyEntityResource {
    @PostMapping(value = "", produces = MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity postResult(@RequestBody Resource<Entity> entity) {
        // my logic. Fetch the entity with entity.getContent()
    }
}
```

You can fetch the entity itself using `entity.getContent()`